# SharePoint Online - Archival Process besides Export to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate, powerapp

We have a SharePoint online list where we have users filling in a "new request" form (power apps customized form).

Then an approver edits the form to add their details and then a processor edits the form to add their details. We would like to be able to archive on a monthly basis not only by performing an "export to excel" but to also save each individual form out to a shared drive (pdf would be preferred but images would work too).

I have googled this in every manner which I could think of to no successful end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scheduled Power Automate flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks) to perform such archiving operations in SharePoint online.

You can run this scheduled flow on a monthly basis. You can either move this list items to another location (site/subsite/list) or create PDF documents using the information in list item columns & save it another location (document library on same site OR OneDrive).

Following references will help you to get started with this:

1. [How to Archive Completed Items in a SharePoint List](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-archive-completed-items-in-sharepoint-list/)
2. [Schedule recurrence to move SharePoint list items to another list using Microsoft Flow](http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/04/29/auto-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-flow/)
3. [Convert a SharePoint List item to PDF Using Microsoft Flow](https://saddamk.blogspot.com/2019/10/convert-sharepoint-list-item-to-pdf.html)
4. [Generate PDF from SharePoint list item](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Generate-PDF-from-SharePoint-list-item/td-p/195965)

Comment: My company does not allow the connection to One Drive for Business....Is there a way I do #3 without using it?

Comment: There might be another ways to generate PDF from SP list item, you can easily find them on internet. Also, there are few paid/premium connectors available for this.